# Java6 RuntimeException that returns Http status code

Tags: java

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212239/what-java-exception-class-to-use-for-http-errors) showing how we can create our own checked exceptions that also return a HTTP status code different from 500. However, I need it to be a `RuntimeException`. 
Then, I found [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) which is an unchecked exception, returns a HTTP status code but does not allow me to set message as in a regular exception.

Is there any unchecked exception out there in Java EE 6 that allows me to set an error message like in a regular exception and also returns a HTTP status code that I can set?

**Edit:** Including an explanation of why I want this as requested by John.

I created a filter to catch HTML and XSS attacks from my requests parameters. Instead of checking for that everytime in `Filter.doFilter` which would be too slow, I extended `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and used it like this.

```
HttpFilterRequest implements Filter
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(new SafeHttpRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
    } catch (SecurityViolationException e) {
        log.warn(format("A security violation was detected. Please enable debug for further details: %s]", e.getMessage()));
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.sendError(e.getStatusCode());
    }response);
  }

SafeHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper (supressing parts to shorten code)
  @Override
  public String getParameter(String parameter) {
      return xssAndHtmlValidation(super.getParameter(parameter));
  }
  @Override
  public String getHeader(String name) {
      return xssAndHtmlValidation(super.getHeader(name));
  }
```

`xssAndHtmlValidation()` throws `SecurityViolationException` which is a  `RuntimeException` but the `catch` block at `doFilter` doesn't work because my exception is thrown as a `ServletException` containing `SecurityViolationException`.

Comment: Override WebApplicationException with your own class

Comment: You can also create your own *unchecked* exceptions.  Just extend `RuntimeException` or one of its descendants, instead of extending an exception class that does not descend from `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Doesn't this do it: `WebApplicationException(String message, int status)`? Or are you looking to have a `setMessage(String message)` method?

Comment: @john I could extend RuntimeException directly, but how would I make the HTTP status code be different from 500?

Comment: @markbernard `WebApplicationException` doesn't have that constructor.

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes It does in Java EE 7. So I guess it is just recent.

Comment: @markbernard Thanks for the news. Unfortunately I'm with Java 6.

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes, if you write your own custom exception, you can assign it any properties you want.  When you initialize an instance, before throwing it, you set those properties however is appropriate.  If you wish, you provide a constructor that allows you to do so.  But this seems too simple.  I'm inclined to think there is a disconnect somewhere here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for your reply. The point is: I need the JVM mechanism to understand that my Exception should return a different http status code to client. How to do it? What property should I set?

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes, I'm not following you.  You want to throw an exception that carries a customizable message and information about an HTTP response code.  But *what code* is going to throw this exception, and *what code* is supposed to handle it?  If you're hoping that code outside your control is going to handle it, then you are not free to choose random exception classes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger exceptions that are not treated (including unchecked exceptions) are raised to the client with status code 500 by default. I found options to change that status code for checked exceptions, such as the ones I referenced in my question. I need to do the same with an unchecked exception. Example (and obviously just an example): NullPointerException thrown to the client as a 400 status code.

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes, I'll try this one last time.  You are describing the exception-handling behavior of some particular method of some particular class.  That behavior is specific to that method, and it is possibly contingent on the state and context of the object on which the method is invoked.  I asked you to tell me which method of which class that is, that is (intended to be) *catching* the exception.  Without that information, we are done.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I had misunderstood your previous message and that's why I didn't answer you. You might have noticed that English isn't my nature language so please be patient. I'll update my post to explain what you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that you want `SafeHttpRequest.xssAndHtmlValidation()` to throw an exception that can pass out of `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` and `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`, neither of which declares any checked exceptions.  You want this exception ultimately to be caught by `HttpFilterRequest.doFilter()`.  You want it to have a customizable message and you want it to carry an HTTP response code.

You clearly do need an unchecked exception to approach the problem this way.  It seems most appropriate to create a new one from scratch, by extending `java.lang.RuntimeException`.  You can give that class whatever fields, constructors, and methods you want, by which to transport any information at all from `xssAndHtmlValidation()` to the filter.  Doing so for an exception class is no different from doing so for any other class, though your constructors should be sure to invoke an appropriate superclass constructor.

The filter must then have a catch block for the new custom exception type.  Since it is your own custom exception, it is unlikely to be caught by anything between the request and the filter, and since you will catch that specific exception, you can easily invoke whatever nice methods you provided for yourself, such as maybe a `getResponseCode()`.  Presumably the catch block would then invoke one of the `sendError()` methods on the response object, *and then return normally* rather than throwing an exception up the stack.

Do note, by the way, that if the problem is detected too late, after the underlying resource has already committed to a different response, then attempting to `sendError()` will cause an `IllegalStateException` instead of changing the response code.  The client won't see that (because, again, the response has already been committed), but the response might be truncated.

Note also that it is unclear whether you actually need your custom exception to carry an HTTP response code.  Would it ever vary from one instance to another?  If not, then the appropriate response code is inherent in the fact that the exception was thrown at all, and the filter can set a response code appropriately based solely on the fact that it has caught that particular exception type.

**Update:**

Of course, if your JSP engine is going to wrap your exception and throw it as a `ServletException` then you can catch that exception and decide what to do based on `exception.getCause().getClass()` (but do watch out for the cause being `null`).  That could work if the engine has not already committed the response in such cases.

If your JSP engine is after all going to intercept all exceptions and convert them into HTTP code 500 responses, then any approach based on throwing an exception is simply a dead end.  Your best option then is to handle it on the front end, in your filter, before passing the request down the chain.  That's a natural fit for a filter.

You expressed concern that doing the test in the filter would be too slow, but that could be slower than your proposed alternative only if the request contains parameters or headers that are never examined by downstream components.  On the other hand, your approach based on a request wrapper could in fact be the slower one if request headers or parameters are accessed more than once each downstream, as you will perform the validation on each access, even though you only need to perform it once per parameter / header.

Comment: That's I thought would happen, but I got a `ServletException` instead of the exception I created from scratch. Here it is:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: br.com.popular.security.exception.HtmlAttackException: An HTTP request was received with HTML code that violates our security standards.: <IMG SRC="javascript:alert(104);">.`

**Edit**: `HtmlAttackException` extends `SecurityViolationException`.

Comment: The question was about an exception that can carry an HTTP response code.  I have answered that and then some.  I have now also updated my response with some commentary about how you could approach your actual problem, given that it seems the exception-based approach is not viable for you.